# set submitted value for image in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter

I have a form with 3 fields.

All the 3 fields are mandatory and have validation rules.

When I submit the form, I am able to set the submitted values for text field by using `set_value();`

How to set the submitted value of an image?

If i submit the form again Its asking me to upload image again.

post_plot  (view)

```
<form method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
<label>Property Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo set_value('Title'); ?>" />
</div>
<div>
<label>Property type</label>
<input type="text" name="type" value="<?php echo set_value('type'); ?>" />
</div>

<div>
<label>File</label>
<input type="file" name="img" value="<?php echo set_value('img'); ?>" />
</div>

<div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

Plot controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Plot extends CI_Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('Admin_layout');
        $this->load->model('admin/plot_model');
        $this->config->load('plot_rules');
        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
        $this->new_name='';
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if (!$this->auth->loggedin()) {
            redirect('admin/login');
        }
    }


    public function add(){


     $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->config->item('plot_settings'));
     $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p><b>', '</b></p>');

     $data["plot_attrib"] = $this->config->item("plot_attribute");
     $data["plot_attrib"]['title'] = 'Add Plot';
     $data["plot_attrib"]['action'] = base_url('admin/plot/add');

     $location = $this->plot_model->get_location();
     $property_type = $this->plot_model->get_property_type();

     $data["plot_attrib"]['location_dropdown'] = $location;

     $data["plot_attrib"]['property_dropdown'] = $property_type;
     $data["plot_attrib"]["error"] = ' ' ;

     $add_attributes = $data["plot_attrib"];
    // echo '<pre>'; print_r($add_attributes); echo '</pre>';


      if ($this->form_validation->run('submit') == FALSE ) 
      {

            $this->admin_layout->set_title('Post Plot');  
            $this->admin_layout->view('admin/post_plot',$add_attributes);
      } 
      else {

            $img = "img";   
            $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']  = 1024;
            $config['max_width']  = 1024;
            $config['max_height'] = 768;

            $this->new_name = 'plot_'.round(microtime(true));
            $config['file_name'] = $this->new_name;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload('img')){


                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                //echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';

                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
                $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['width']         = 500;
                $config['height']       = 500;

                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

                $this->image_lib->resize();

                $config['source_image'] = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
                $config['wm_text'] = 'Copyright Feroz Akbar :P';
                $config['wm_type'] = 'text';
                //$config['wm_font_path'] = './system/fonts/texb.ttf';
                $config['wm_font_size'] = '10';
                $config['wm_font_color'] = 'ffffff';
                $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
                $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
                $config['wm_padding'] = '5';

                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

                $this->image_lib->watermark();

                $this->new_name = $data['upload_data']['orig_name'];

                $this->admin_layout->view('admin/post_plot',$add_attributes);
                $this->insert();
            }else{
                $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $add_attributes['error'] = $error;

                $this->admin_layout->view('admin/post_plot',$add_attributes);
            }


        }



    }//add

}
```

Comment: i have set some validation rules for property title and property type .
eg: if error occurs for property title  ,error is displayed, after giving the correct data for  property title , i try to submit the form again..
that time it asks me to upload the image file again.

Property type filed is fine ...it repopulates the submitted value.
but why not the image?

Comment: submit your controller code too?

Comment: when you have validation errors in other fields except image then upload that image to some other temp folder and display it back OR set callback handle as shown here http://keighl.com/post/codeigniter-file-upload-validation/